# How come I used the maximum amount of votes possible and I didn't get the Suffrage nor the Vox Populi badges?

Tags: bug

Must be a bug.

Bug behavior details:
I had set the app to track "Vox Populi" progress, it didn't register "Suffrage" when I went past 30 votes and it got stuck at 35 vote count.

> Using Chrome on original Windows 10 license running on MacBook Pro with Boot Camp, everything up to date.
>   Google Chrome is up to date
>   Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I don't actually care about badges, but is hard to not get carried away with gamification sometimes.

Comment: Badges that aren't that common aren't awarded immediately. There's a script than runs from time to time, and you'd be awarded "suffrage" in a while. As for being stuck in 35 votes, the way the system implements voting is 30 votes + 10 bonus on questions, and you haven't voted on enough questions.

Comment: to expand on M.A.R.'s explanation of how many votes you have, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213) it is explained at length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing about votes is that you don't necessarily always have 40 votes. To cite for example [Daily vote limit reached on 37 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113513/352819):

> There is a [limit of 30 all-purpose votes per day and 10 question-only votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes).
>
> The tricky part is that you have to spend your questions-only votes first.

There are special votes that can only be used to upvote questions and these have to be used first if you want to have a total of 40 votes on any day.

It just so happens that today you have a maximum of 35 votes. If you want the badge you have to upvote questions first and then spend the rest on answers.

It also takes a while for badges to be awarded. There are different batches running that award badges. If you met the requirements for a badge and it still wasn't awarded after 24 hours or so it may be a bug, but everything up to that can be called "normal".